# java IF statement condition is being ignored

Tags: java, if-statement

my programme is making  snake game the snake is moving up and down and doesn't move   right and left

```
package snake2;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class Snake extends Frame implements MouseListener{

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {


  if (e.getX()>x[0])
     {
          incx=1;
          incy=0;
     }
  if (e.getX()<x[0])
    {
         incx=-1;
         incy=0;
    }   
  if( e.getY()>y[0])
     {
        incx=0;      
        incy=1;
     }
  if(e.getY()<y[0]) 
    {
        incx=0;
        incy=-1;
    }

} 


@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
  int incx=1,incy=0;
 int[] x = new int[300];
 int[] y = new int [300];
 int len=5;
 public Label l;

public Snake() 
{
    setSize(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    l = new Label("snake lenght ="+ len);
    add(l,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    x[0]=100;
    y[0]=100;

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Snake s = new Snake();
    move m = new move();
    m.ptr=s;
    m.start();
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<=len;i++)
    g.fillRect(x[i], y[i], 10, 10);        
}
public void shift()
{
    for (int z=len;z>0;z--)
    {
            x[z]=x[z-1];
            y[z]=y[z-1];
    }


}
}

 class move extends Thread
{

   Snake ptr;

   int count=0;

  public void run()
 {
    for (;;)
    {
          ptr.shift();
           count++;
           ptr.x[0]=ptr.x[0]+ptr.incx*10;
           ptr.y[0]=ptr.y[0]+ptr.incy*10;
           ptr.repaint();
           try{sleep(150);}catch(Exception a){}

           if(count%5==0){
             ptr.len++;}
          ptr. l.setText("snake lenght ="+ ptr.len);

             for (int z = ptr.len; z > 0; z--) {

     if ((z > 4) && (ptr.x[0] == ptr.x[z]) && (ptr.y[0] == ptr.y[z])) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You lost");
          }
      }

    if (ptr.y[0] >500) {
      JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You lost");
    }

    if (ptr.y[0] < 0) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You lost");
    }

    if (ptr.x[0] > 500) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You lost");
    }

    if (ptr.x[0] < 0) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "You lost");
    }


        }

    }

}
```

the problem in my programme that it skip the first 2 IF statements, it just skip X and    if i changed the X  with the Y it skip Y and do X and start moving right and left and stop going up and down.

Answer (score 7):

You need to check as below because if y axis is changed then you are resetting the changes made in `x` and a mouse can be along x and y axis simultaniously

```
if (e.getX()>x[0])
{
    incx=1;
} else if (e.getX()<x[0])
{
    incx=-1;
}   
if( e.getY()>y[0])
{
    incy=1;
} else if(e.getY()<y[0]) 
{
    incy=-1;
}
```

Comment: i tried this and it worked but it didn't move like the game snake

Comment: @user2304626 can you share how the variables incx and incy are used?